# force .GRP counter to start from 2 instead of 1 in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

**How to force .GRP in data.table to start the group counter from 2 instead of 1?**

I have a data.table with groups which I want to sequentially order by group.

```
example_data.table <- data.table(Var1 = c(1,2,2,4,5,5,5), Var2 = c(1,2,3,7,1,2,3) )
```

[image]

When I use .GRP counter it starts with very first combination as conter 1.

```
Group_table   <- setDT(example_data.table)[, label := .GRP, by = c("Var1", "Var2" )]
```

[image]

But I want to set group with **Var1** value as **4** and **Var2** value as **7** to counter value  **1** and then the next.

[image]

How do I use .GRP in such a way that **Var1** as **4** and **Var2** as **7** takes a counter as **1** and others in next order?

So, what I was thinking is manually give counter as 1 for the needed combination and for others start the counter from 2 . There are other ways too but I am just a bit confused.

Comment: You need to give a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @KumarManglam Thanks for the comments! I have updated the qs with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3):

If you only have one entry with `Var1 = 4 & Var2 = 7`, then you can remove that entry from `.GRP`, and use `replace` to replace it with 1, i.e.

```
library(data.table)

dt1[-(which(dt1$Var1 == 4 & dt1$Var2 == 7)), Counter := .GRP + 1, by = c('Var1', 'Var2')][, 
                                                Counter := replace(Counter, is.na(Counter), 1)][]
```

which gives,

> ```
>    Var1 Var2 Counter
> 1:    1    1       2
> 2:    2    2       3
> 3:    2    3       4
> 4:    4    7       1
> 5:    5    1       5
> 6:    5    2       6
> 7:    5    3       7
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one Qs. Why have you used [ ] at last again? Can't we do without it?

Comment: The brackets at the end are just for displaying the result. You don't have to put them.

Answer (score 3):

If you want certain groups to "start" the count, you can use `order` to sort during construction:

```
ex = copy(example_data.table)
ex[order(Var1 != 4, Var2 != 7), g := .GRP, by=.(Var1, Var2)][]

   Var1 Var2 g
1:    1    1 2
2:    2    2 3
3:    2    3 4
4:    4    7 1
5:    5    1 5
6:    5    2 6
7:    5    3 7
```